# Python Pandas Dataframe: Select entries based on conditions in second dataframe (date range and condition)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to select entries from one dataframe conditional on another dataframe using Pythons pandas dataframes:

The first dataframe gives the prioritized date of each person:

```
import pandas as pd
df_priority = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alfred', 'Bob', 'Charles'], 'Start Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-05-01'] , 'End Date': ['2018-02-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-06-01']})
df_priority.head()
```

```
     Start Date  End Date    Person
0   2018-01-01  2018-02-01  Alfred
1   2018-03-01  2018-04-01  Bob
2   2018-05-01  2018-06-01  Charles
```

The second dataframe gives the sales value for each person and month:

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alfred', 'Alfred', 'Alfred','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles'],'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01','2018-04-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01','2018-04-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'], 'Sales': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
df_sales.head(15)
```

```
    Date    Person  Sales
0   2018-01-01  Alfred  1
1   2018-02-01  Alfred  2
2   2018-03-01  Alfred  3
3   2018-01-01  Bob 4
4   2018-02-01  Bob 5
5   2018-03-01  Bob 6
6   2018-04-01  Bob 7
7   2018-05-01  Bob 8
8   2018-06-01  Bob 9
9   2018-01-01  Charles 10
10  2018-02-01  Charles 11
11  2018-03-01  Charles 12
12  2018-04-01  Charles 13
13  2018-05-01  Charles 14
14  2018-06-01  Charles 15
```

Now, i want the sales number for each person during his prioritized Date range, i.e. the outcome should be:

```
    Date    Person  Sales
0   2018-01-01  Alfred  1
1   2018-02-01  Alfred  2
5   2018-03-01  Bob 6
6   2018-04-01  Bob 7
13  2018-05-01  Charles 14
14  2018-06-01  Charles 15
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lambda on several columns to achieve the desired outcome:

```
# custom function that gives the prioritized date range for each person by person name
def salesByNameAndDate(name):
    start_date = df_priority[df_priority['Person'] == name]['Start Date'].values[0]
    end_date = df_priority[df_priority['Person'] == name]['End Date'].values[0]
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
    return date_range

# return sales value if the date is inside the date range for this person or "nothing" if the date is outside this range
df_sales['new_sales'] = df_sales.apply(lambda x: x['Sales'] if x['Date'] in salesByNameAndDate(x['Person']) else 'nothing',axis=1)

# after that you drop all "nothing" and duplicate column "new_sales"
new_df = df_sales[df_sales['new_sales'] != 'nothing'].drop('new_sales', axis=1)[['Date', 'Person', 'Sales']]

# output
  Date   Person  Sales
0   2018-01-01   Alfred      1
1   2018-02-01   Alfred      2
5   2018-03-01      Bob      6
6   2018-04-01      Bob      7
13  2018-05-01  Charles     14
14  2018-06-01  Charles     15
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is join the dataframes using some unique identifier (and I hope name is that unique identifier), filter the new dataframe using the end_date and then group-up:

```
df=df_sales.join(df_priority, on='Person', how='left')  
df[(df.['End Date']>df.Date) & (df['Start Date']<df.Date)].groupby('Person','Date').sum()
```

Left join's the default option in join method, but just making it clear that left join would make more sense. You have to make sure that both columns are date time datatype. You can use: `pandas.to_datetime()` to ensure that.